# Mysql foreign key referencing same table error General error: 1822 Failed to add the foreign key constraint. Missing index for constraint

Tags: mysql, laravel

I have a table
`mytable`

```
-- auto-generated definition
create table mytable
(
    id           varchar(255)                                                                                                                                  not null,
    name       varchar(255)                                                                                                                                  not null,
    parent_id    varchar(255)                                                                                                                                  null
)
    collate = utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

I want to make `parent_id` a foreign key to mytable.id

```
create index mytable_parent_id_index
    on mytable (parent_id);
alter table `mytable` add constraint `mytable_parent_id_foreign` foreign key (`parent_id`) references `mytable` (`id`);
```

the above is failing.

I am actually using Laravel migrations and do not write the mysql myself.

The code that gets executed is:

```
<?php declare(strict_types = 1);

use App\Support\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateMyTableTable extends Migration
{
    private const TABLE = 'mytable';

    public function up(): void
    {
        Schema::create(self::TABLE, function (Blueprint $table): void {
            $table->string('id')->primary();
            $table->string('parent_id')->nullable()->index();
            $table->foreign('parent_id')->references('id')->on('places');
        });
    }

    public function down(): void
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists(self::TABLE);
    }
}
```

You can see that I use `->index()` on the parent_id field as well.

My question is:
How to have this working so that parent_id references as foreign key id on the same table?

Comment: For future related issue see [Conditions and Restrictions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html#foreign-key-restrictions)

Answer (score 1):

The parent_id has to be a integer. I recommend using a bigInteger, this gives you a larger range.

```
<?php declare(strict_types = 1);

use App\Support\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateMyTableTable extends Migration
{
    private const TABLE = 'mytable';

    public function up(): void
    {
        Schema::create(self::TABLE, function (Blueprint $table): void {
            $table->id();
            $table->bigInteger('parent_id')->unsigned()->nullable()->index();
            $table->foreign('parent_id')->references('id')->on('places');
        });
    }

    public function down(): void
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists(self::TABLE);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but why ? The id table is string as well so parentid cannot be integer using as foreign key a string type

Comment: Hi, sorry forgot to edit it. the id has to be ->id(). I edited my answer. You will also need to edit the constant with the mytable to your table name

Comment: **The parent_id has to be a bigInteger.** Why ?

Comment: @ErgestBasha I have rephrased my answer as it looks like its mandatory. You can also use a normal integer. But in many modern db systems, using a biginteger is becoming more common. Mainly because of the growing datasets. Big integers can handle bigger numbers.

Comment: @luukd your answer is wrong. The reason why the OP alter statement fail is that id column should be indexed. See https://dbfiddle.uk/AKYuEdGT

Comment: @ErgestBasha As you can see in my answer, I edited the primary key column to the ->id(); The primary key does not have to be indexed. Indexing the id does speed things up, but it is not required.

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue.

The foreign key cannot be added without the table being created first.

Needed to run a second separate script

```
        Schema::table(self::TABLE, function (Blueprint $table): void {
            $table->foreign('parent_id')->references('id')->on('mytable');
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message you're seeing, "Missing index for constraint," is indicating that you need to add an index to the column you're referencing in the foreign key constraint.

Here's how you can modify your migration to fix the issue:

```
class CreateMyTableTable extends Migration
{
    private const TABLE = 'mytable';

    public function up(): void
    {
        Schema::create(self::TABLE, function (Blueprint $table): void {
            $table->string('id')->primary();
            $table->string('parent_id')->nullable(); // Remove the index here
        });

        Schema::table(self::TABLE, function (Blueprint $table): void {
            $table->index('parent_id'); // Add the index after creating the table
            $table->foreign('parent_id')->references('id')->on(self::TABLE);
        });
    }

    public function down(): void
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists(self::TABLE);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes I realised the same myself after some time https://stackoverflow.com/a/77007564/5638943